# Laravel 5.5 file directory by database data

Tags: laravel

This is my Controller

```
$directory = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.'a'.'/'.'b'.'/'.'c'.'/';
```

its not working as well. i think its not takes $project->division and user and created at.

```
$project = Project::find($project->id);
$diviz = Project::find($project->division);
$user = Project::find($project->user);
$create = Project::find($project->created_at);
$comments = $project->comments;
$directory = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$diviz.'/'.$user.'/'.$create.'/';
$files = Storage::files($directory);
return view('projects.show', ['project'=>$project, 'comments'=> $comments ])->with(array('files' => $files));
```

This is my Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'description',
    'division',
    'who',
    'whom',
    'content',
    'user',
    'filename'
];
```

This is my migration

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('division')->nullable();
        $table->string('who')->nullable();
        $table->string('whom')->nullable();
        $table->string('content')->nullable();
        $table->text('user');
        $table->text('filename');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: i fixed it nvm thanks. created_at was like 2018-01-15 12:12:05 and my folder name was like 2018-01-15-12-12-05 that was the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your problem is about this line of code

```
$directory = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$diviz.'/'.$user.'/'.$create.'/';
```

then your using it wrong. $diviz, $user, $create are **Model Class**, your trying to concatenate those those class with a string which will would result a different output.

Comment: `protected $fillable = [
        'description',
        'division',
        'who',
        'whom',
        'content',
        'user',
        'filename'
    ];`

Comment: the value of your variable $directory is still wrong. 
maybe you mean something like this


**$directory = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$project->division.'/'.$project->user.'/'.$project->created_at.'/';**

Comment: `$destinationPath = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$division.'/'.$userName.'/'.$date.'/';` it was working as well in Store function

Comment: the best way is debug your variables first, check if storing the right value by using **var_dump** or **return** inside your controller.

you might want to **return $directory**

Comment: i tried 'return $directory' it gives to me right directory to me